# click won't work on collapsible bootstrap table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I tried to make accordion table using bootstrap on react with jsx but It shows collapsed text at the start also clicking function won't work. I tried to convert div examples into table but couldn't figured how should I convert more than one div into table design. It

```
    {props.users.map((user, i) => (
                    <Fragment>
                        <tr key={i} className="accordion-button" data-bs-target={"#Collapse" + i} aria-expanded="true" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-controls={"collapse" + i} >
                            <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                            <td>{user.name}</td>
                            <td>{user.mail}</td>
                            <td>{user.contact}</td>
                            <td><Link type="button"
                                to={`edit/${user.id}`}
                                className="btn btn-md btn-outline-primary"
                            >Edit</Link></td>
                            <td><button className="btn btn-md btn-outline-danger" data-target={i} onClick={(event) => props.deleteUserProp(user)}>Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id={"Collapse" + i} className="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent={"#accordionExample" + i}>
                            <td colSpan="6" className="accordion-body">
                                <strong>This is the {i} item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
  </td>
                        </tr>
                    </Fragment>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that I have to import the js library of bootstrap too.  After I added the code below, it worked.

"/node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";